# The 4G/LTE Huawei E3276 modem does not work on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on an asus ROG laptop G74sx. I have a 4G wireless broadband modem HUAWEI E3276. When I plug it in the "enable mobile broadband" does not appear.

When I run `lsusb` I get the following:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2885 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card reader
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 045e:0773 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 152d:0539 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
```

Ubuntu seems to recognize the modem as Huawei E398. But I cannot get it to work. 
Any help will be much appreciated. And please keep your answers as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news my friend. This device does not run on Linux. It is not compatible. I knnow this because I had a client with the same one.

These USB modems are hit & miss. Some work with Linux, some do not. It is always best to research such things before you buy.

If it is possible, I would reccomend going instead with a portable hotspot because they simply create a wifi network for your devices to connect to Thus, your OS doesnt matter as much. or if you have an Android phone, check to see if it has hotspot or tethering capabilities, many do. But as a rider to this, check with your carrier to make sure tethering is allowed on your plan.

I have the Mifi 2000 from virgin, & it works great & right now is on sale for $20 on the virgin mobile website. (I paid $80 for mine, so get it while its cheap).

Comment: Oh & by the way, the Mifi is also avaialble through Verizon I think.